В чем проблема тестирования минимального api (java-postman)?
Осваиваю создание api.
При поптыке протестировать через Postman ловлю ошибки о недоступности. Пробовал отправлять запрос, как на локалхост, так и по IP для обоих GET - получаю ошибку о недоступности пути.
В Postman даже прописывал прокси на локалхост, но без результата.
Помогите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка, что нужно исправить?
controller
import com.example.apilearn.entity.Cat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @GetMapping("/api/main")
    public String mainListener(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/cat")
    public String giveCat(){
        Cat cat = new Cat("Barsik", 10, 7);
        String jsonData = null;

        try {
            jsonData = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cat);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return jsonData;
    }

}

entity
@Getter
@Setter
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
public class Cat {
     String name;
     int age;
     int weight;

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Cat() {
    }
}

application.properties
server.port=8080

Main
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApilearnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApilearnApplication.class, args);
    }
}

При любом запросе из Postman, например localhost:8080/api/cat
ловлю:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-12-08T06:19:49.879+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/cat"
}


Указанная ошибка возникает только в постмане?  Что получается при обращении к данному URL при помощи браузера и/или curl?

По URL. Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).  По CURL тот же 404/not found

Значит, ошибка в конфигурации прилоожения, а не постмана. См. EngSO: Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404), вероятно, спринг не смог найти ваш контроллер, и вам следует добавить аннотацию @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MainController.class) над классом ApilearnApplication

Сделайте это ответом, я отмечу решением. Спасибо большое, это работает для "/api/main"! Но появилась вторая проблема: "/api/cat" возвращает ошибку. При этом, коду не нравится анатации и AllArgsConstructor NoArgsConstructor, пишет "java: constructor Cat in class com.example.apilearn.entity.Cat cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    java.lang.String,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length". Если создаю конструкторы  - то приложение компилируется. Может и тут знаете в чем подвох?

Как вы компилируете свой проект, в IntelliJ Idea?  Если да, скорее всего проблема с конфигурацией Lombok в вашем IDE -- нужно разрешить обработку аннотаций Build, Execution, Deployment  Compiler  Annotation Processors: опция Enable annotation processing Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA

разобрался с завиясимостями плагина ломбока. Зааработало. Спасибо большое. Напишите коммент, отмечу реешнием. Вы правда очень сильно помогли!
